# Facebook Id temporarily locked while fetching data from different location

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-comments

I am trying to fetch comments from Facebook and trying reply that from the application using the access token again a facebook id. 
When I am using that from one location continuously it works well even on dynamic IP of my system for days .. but when I tries to use the same at my home.. it is working for 2 times hardly and then blocks the ID... please help me resolve this.

Code here :

```
string AccessToken = "Acess token here";
GET_POST_LINK posts;
string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/mefields=posts%7Bmessage%2Cpermalink_url%7D&access_token=" + AccessToken + "";
HttpWebRequest feedRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
feedRequest.Method = "GET";
feedRequest.Accept = "application/json";
feedRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
WebResponse feedResponse = (HttpWebResponse)feedRequest.GetResponse();
using (feedResponse)
       {
           using (var reader = new StreamReader(feedResponse.GetResponseStream()))
           {
               posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GET_POST_LINK>(reader.ReadToEnd());
               int count = posts.posts.data.Count;
           }
       }
```

Comment: What do you mean it blocks the ID? Exactly what error do you get? What API call are you making?

Comment: I am trying to fetch comments with facebook graph api, code used :        
string AccessToken = "Acess token here"; GET_POST_LINK posts; string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/mefields=posts%7Bmessage%2Cpermalink_url%7D&access_token=" + AccessToken + ""; HttpWebRequest feedRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); feedRequest.Method = "GET"; feedRequest.Accept = "application/json"; feedRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

Comment: code continued : WebResponse feedResponse = (HttpWebResponse)feedRequest.GetResponse(); using (feedResponse) { using (var reader = new StreamReader(feedResponse.GetResponseStream())) { posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(reader.ReadToEnd()); int count = posts.posts.data.Count; } }

Comment: don't post your code in comment, Update your question with code.

Comment: And please answer all questions I had

Comment: my facebook ID is getting blocked in 3 days of using any access token.. and the error is coming as " Please upload a photo of yourself that clearly shows your face. We'll check it and then permanently delete it from our servers." and I am calling the Graph API.. please help